# how to add a uipickerview as a sub view in a uitableviewcell using monotouch?

Tags: ipad, c#-4.0, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

- I have implemented a grid-looking structure (say 5 rows and 10
  columns) for an iPad. I have done this by adding many UITextFileds(by
  creating Frames) as subviews(each cell being editable, just like an
  excel sheet) in a single row of a UItableViewCell.
- Now my task is to have a pull/drop down menu when the user clicks on
  any cell.I found this a difficult to implement, as I am new to
  monotouch. So I decided to go for the default UIPicker(drum like
  structure).
- **So this is what I want to achieve now, when the user clicks on the cell in the lower half of the screen of the iPad I would want the
  picker element(the drum) to show up and the user could click on the
  value to choose a value (different fields may have a different range of values).**
- **BottomLine I want to add UIPicker to a UItableViewcell using monotouch**(N.B. Normal procedure using monotouch dialog declares picker elements in a section under a rootelement, I can't do that here I guess.)

So Kindly tell me how to go about it,or if there is any better way to achieve this drop-down  experience keeping the grid intact.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `UIActionSheet` instead?  It displays a popup bubble with a number of buttons to select from.  You'll see it in other apps.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers : I am wondering if I can use a UIPopOverController (with a customised list to display for each cell), but I am not sure if a UIPopOverController can be linked to the Frame of UITextField... trying to look into it... gimme some links if you find them before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For item 3 in your list: you could use UIPopoverController on a iPad, in which you could place UIPicker or any other controls. Demo: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/Popovers will help you.

[image: Screenshot of demo]

You could fire UIPopoverController in UITableViewSource (UITableViewDelegate) subclass on RowSelected event.

For item 4 in your list: if you want to add UIPicker right in a UITableViewCell, for example, in the last one, you should do such things:

- Declare your own UITableViewCell subclass, which creates UIPicker within itself;
- On UITableView.GetCell event check that indexPath points to last one cell. If so, create your custom UITableViewCell.